# Touchpad device has a malformed name (tab character included), how to fix it?

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, input-devices, xinput

My touchpad can be detected as a USB device,

```
$ lsusb | grep touchpad
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 06cb:2970 Synaptics, Inc. touchpad
```

But when it is queried by xinput or libinput-list-devices, it has a strange device name:

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳     Touchpad                              id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
...
```

The tab prefix of Touchpad is preventing many touchpad configuration tools from finding it (e.g. KDE system settings). How do I manually correct it?